# spring data cassandra with datastax driver 3

Tags: spring, cassandra

I know that currently spring-data-cassandra is using driver 2.0.x.

On which spring-data-cassanda version does driver version 3.x is planned?

I couldnt find in documentations

Answer (score 1):

I looked into the source code. It's only a wrapper for the java datastax driver. You can do two things: You can use the java driver and map your objects by yourself or you can test this source code: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/commit/a920b530df039415693c3cb65485a6b44cab6144 It's also available in the master branch. It looks like the new version 1.5.x will include the cassandra 3.0 support.